# Change the size of the colorbar in geopandas plot.I got error "Unknown property cax"

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to adjust the size of the colorbar in geopandas.plot() function.

I read geopandas' Github page about the colorbar adjustment.
https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/894

Then wrote the code as follow

```py
import geopandas as gp
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
shp=gp.read_file("PropRepShape.shp",encoding="UTF-8")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.2) # depends on the user needs
shp.plot("P_NUM",ax=ax,cax=cax,legend=True,cmap=cmap)
```

"PropRepShape.shp" is available from 
https://github.com/ShingObt/2019JapanHOCElectionMap/tree/master/Shapefile

Then I end up getting the error message that says

`AttributeError: Unknown property cax`

By removing `cax=cax` I can generate the map but the size of the colorbar is not adjusted.

Could you let me know the way to successfully use cax argument in gp.plot?

Comment: Which version of geopandas are you using?

Comment: @mishsx please refrain from abusing bold formatting like you did in your edit on this question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327171/6296561

Comment: I use geopandas 0.4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cax` property has been implemented in geopandas 0.5.0 (see the [changelog](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/releases/tag/v0.5.0)). You will have to update to 0.5.1 (stable) or 0.6.0rc1 (release candidate) to use `cax` within your code.

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas=0.5.1
```

Comment: Thank you! I updated geopandas to 0.5.1 and cax worked well. From the next time, I'll check the version carefully.